# How to use jQueryValidation without using name attributes

Tags: jquery-validate, name-attribute

I'm using [jQueryValidation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and I would like to validate my form without needing to use `name` attributes.

If the form elements don't have the `name` attribute only the first element is validated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Validation Demo</title>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loginButton').click(function(){
                $('form').validate();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" id="loginForm">
            <input type="text" id="userText" class="required" placeholder="User" />
            <input type="password" id="passwordText" class="required" placeholder="Password" />
            <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Surely the name attributes are useful for handling the data? What's your problem with using them?

Comment: Have you tried validating an element like this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element?

Comment: @Calum none, I just wasn't properly understanding the differences between them.

Comment: @Calum When using Stripe we don't ever want to pass data to the server, so not using a name attribute on the inputs makes sense. Instead, we use a data attribute so Stripe.js can pick them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `name` attribute in order to use `class="required"`

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
   $("#loginForm").validate({

                rules: {
                      userText:"required"
                       }
                     });
```

Comment: OP said he wants to validate elements by ID instead of name